# JDBC connection pool get and close frequency

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

I have an application where I need to store a lot of events in database. The events are coming at a frequency of 5000 events/minute and the total number of events can go up to millions.

I am using c3po connection pooling. What I planned to do was to **get one connection from the pool for the application ** and use the same connection to persist all the events, like below:

1. Connection conn = //create connection
2. Persistor persistor = new Peristor(conn)//inject the above created connection.

   persistor.persistEvent(Event e) {
   conn.write(e);
   }

statements and result sets are getting closed after every write, but I am not closing the connection (releasing it back to the pool) after every persist. Instead, the connections are closed when application is stopped.

I ran the application and after persisting about 600,000 event, I took a heapdump (using:jmap -dump:format=b,file=test-dump.hprof [PID]) to check what's happening in heap.

I could see that there is a huge object "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection" that consumes 500 MB of heap). On analyzing the object, I could see that it contains recursion of nested objects of the same object (com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection).

So, the question is, is the object huge because I didn't return the connection to the pool after every write, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You do not need the connection pool if you are only going to create one connection and hold it open.

Comment: Something is not clear to me: are you or are you not releasing the connection (conn.close()) after each use?

Comment: And conversely if you have a connection pool you do not need to keep the connection open. You should close it, which returns it to the pool, and get a new one when you need it. This will also insulate you against the server dropping connections.

Comment: @MauricePerry, I am not closing the connection after every write.

Comment: @user2596386 well you should